# Why is C# ASP.NET generally not regarded as a rapid web development framework?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, ruby

The terms rapid web development gets associated with Python/Django and ROR. Why is this not the case with C# ASP.NET?

Comment: Source or it doesn't happen.

Comment: SnOrfus is correct, you need to specify your source or provide us some published data to back up your statment.

Comment: Its just the impression I get browsing the internet. Every new startup that utilises agile developement and rapid prototyping methodologies seem to be using ROR or Pthon/Django

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "rapid development framework" or "rapid development language". Any framework, language, or toolset is equally possible for use in a rapid development environment as any other.

Rapid development has nothing to do with languages or technologies used. Rapid development is a methodology that favors producing prototypes frequently with minimal up-front design and planning.

Comment: What languages/frameworks are best suited for rapid web development methodology then?

Comment: None. It's a methodology that is independent of all languages, frameworks, and tools.

Comment: That is a bold statement that technologies and languages don't impact developer productivity.  So why have we bothered inventing new frameworks and languages over the past several decades?  You are saying that I could develop as quick a web application using ASP.NET or RoR as I could with C++ or Perl through CGI?

Comment: @jkohlhepp This isn't about developer productivity at all. It's about adhering to a specific process or methodology. You can choose to follow the principles of RAD with any language and saying that one language makes following RAD easier is just wrong.

Comment: @Thomas I guess I just plain disagree.  Forgetting the "RAD" buzzword, some frameworks and languages make things quicker to develop than others.  That seemed to me to be what Nai was asking about.

Comment: @jkohlhepp RAD isn't a buzzword, though. It's a well-defined software engineering process methodology. By definition of what a software engineering process methodology is, it must be independent of frameworks and languages.

Comment: @jholkepp: While I agree with your assessment that the tools you use can influence the speed at which you develop, [Wikipedia favors Thomas' use of the term RAD.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development)

Comment: Conflicting terminology it is. Wikipedia's definition for Rapid means quick to action as against to long term planning while in plain English, for most people, it would mean decreasing application's incubation time.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET when developed as an application requires that you compile the project into a dll; it is possible sometimes to make simple changes to the .aspx files and get immediate results but it is not as dynamic as other platforms.

Comment: This is a minimal difference.  It is an extra 5 seconds when hitting Run before you see the app.

Comment: Not really when you have an app with hundreds of pages and classes.

Comment: Not sure what settings you are using, VS will only compile what it needs to. Unless you are forcing a re build every time. I'm modifying code while debugging and the changes are happening fine. And some of the projects very very large indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of development work with ASP.NET.  I don't know much about Python/Django but I have done some reading on Ruby on Rails.  I think the main reason that RoR is considered more RAD than ASP.NET is scaffolding.  ASP.NET does have some scaffolding features (and ASP.NET MVC has even more), but I think RoR's is generally more powerful.  Also, ASP.NET developers in my experience tend not to use the scaffolding features even when they are available.  And the scaffolding features in vanilla ASP.NET tend to lead you down bad architecture and design paths, whereas the scaffolding in RoR tends to lead you down the correct A&D path.

In reality, ASP.NET can be a pretty rapid platform.  For any non-trivial web application, I think the differences between RoR and ASP.NET would be minimal, especially if the developers are proficient in whichever platform.